# how to date format 103 to group by using where clause with string format (varchar(103),...,10)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

Im having trouble on a query with a datetime field.

Its because i convert the datetime field to -varchar(10),..,103- so i can apply a where clause with date field on 103 format instead of datetime but then when i use the where clause it doesnt show results or group the way i need to, because the datetime field was converted to string.

Here is a simplified query for the example:

```
select ddate,SUM(ntotal) as Income from Inc_orders    
where nbranch=2 
and convert(varchar(10),ddate,103)                                   
between '01/06/2010' and '31/06/2010'   
group by convert(varchar(10),ddate,103)  
order by ddfecha desc
```

ddate is the datetime field
ntotal is integer
nbranch is foreign key

**Then what happens is that i get results from another 103 date range**

```
01/10/2009  4447.0000    
02/01/2010  26267.8000    
02/02/2010  20498.0000    
02/04/2010  22565.1000   
02/05/2010  20539.0000    
02/11/2010  33934.3000     
02/12/2009  33587.4000
```

**What i pretend to look it like is :**

```
01/06/2010  29327.7000       
02/06/2010  31170.4000     
03/06/2010  37737.7000     
04/06/2010  25109.6000     
06/06/2010  20819.7000     
10/06/2010  44703.9000     
14/06/2010  21755.1000     
15/06/2010  39369.3000    
05/06/2010  29552.2000    
07/06/2010  35305.9000    
08/06/2010  30628.6000    
..........     
31/06/2010  18677.6000
```

A solution is not using datepart, month, or year functions because i need the 
parameter to look like a calendar to apply a datetimepicker calentad combo object on it.

Comment: why are you converting the datetime at all?

Comment: im converting it so i can aply the object datetimepicker to place diferent intervals on the adoquery for delphi. also is for displaying information on a grid that way.

Comment: just do the reverse, convert the values comming from datepicker to the format "YYYYMMAA" and you will ensure that your app works for any input allways

Comment: ok, but i also need to display the date on the grid on that format dd/mm/yyyy. Im gonna aply it on other forms.  TY

Comment: Diferent things are what you pass to the query and what you obtain from it. So as I suggested, use CONVERT only on the select list to have the best format for you.  But pass params to the query using standards: YYYYMMDD is a no-fail format.  Or use parametrized querys if you have typed data.

Comment: ok, but if i use the condition where `convert(varchar(10),ddate,103)                                   
between '01/06/2010' and '31/06/2010'` it doesnt show the information expected.  because now its a string and not a date.

Comment: I looked for more answers and the solution was on employing the following statement on Delphi ADO sql connection. With dateutils on uses. '+ QUOTEDSTR(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',DateTimePicker1.Date))+'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateField, 103)` to remove the time from `DATETIME` it is inefficient and also causes problems when sorting.

Depending on the version of SQL-Server you are using there are 2 options that are usually regarded as the best. For SQL-Server 2008 and upwards use `CAST(DateField AS DATE)`, for previous versions use `DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateField))`

Because you are converting Ddate to a VARCHAR in this line:

```
convert(varchar(10),ddate,103) between '01/06/2010' and '31/06/2010'
```

you are removing the implicit conversion of '01/06/2010' and '31/06/2010' to dates. This means '02/01/2000' is greater than '01/01/2012' because you are comparing strings not dates. If you remove the time from Ddate and keep the expression in a date(time) format, '01/06/2010' and '31/06/2010' are implicitly converted to dates.

To illustrate this simply you can run this simple query:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN '02/06/2000' BETWEEN '01/06/2012' AND '03/06/2012' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [String Comparison],
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/06/2000') BETWEEN '01/06/2012' AND '03/06/2012' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Date Comparison]
```

So your query would end up something like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

SELECT  CAST(DDate AS DATE) Ddate,
        SUM(ntotal) as Income 
FROM    Inc_orders    
WHERE   nbranch=2 
AND     CAST(DDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01/06/2010' AND '31/06/2010'   
GROUP BY CAST(DDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY DDate
```

Or

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DDate)) Ddate,
        SUM(ntotal) as Income 
FROM    Inc_orders    
WHERE   nbranch=2 
AND     DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DDate)) BETWEEN '01/06/2010' AND '31/06/2010'   
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DDate))
ORDER BY DDate
```

**ADDENDUM**

I am not sure if `Ddate` contains a time, so using the above to remove the time may not be relevant, however the part about comparing strings in the where clause remains relevant. In addition there are very few occassions when it should be necessary to present your date to your application in string format. It would be better to keep the date as a date and format it within you application layer (whatever this may be).

Comment: your answer is very complete i would keep revising the matter because right now its not working that way

Comment: please, do not recommend to use `'DD/MM/YYYY'` format as in `CAST(DDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '01/06/2010' AND '31/06/2010'` because it is language dependant, instead use `'YYYYMMDD'`

Comment: ty all for your answers Luis siquot i converted the valued coming from the datetime picker and that was it ty

Comment: @LuisSiquot While I agree that YYYYMMDD is a better format, note that the query in the answer contains `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` so using `DD/MM/YYYY` is not dependant on database language settings, your comment is therefore moot.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use CONVERT nor in GROUP BY, nor in WHERE.  use convert on SELECT list of fields

**UPDATE:**
See valid and recommended formats for [DATE CONSTANTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#StringLiteralDateandTimeFormats) at Microsoft. Please select a any format with "DATEFORMAT dependent: NO" and "Multilanguage: YES" in order to NOT have any problems in any language/setup

**UPDATE:**
i was writing just the same query @Blorgbeard when I saw:  it wont work, because you cant group only by nbranch and have ddate on select list, also nbranch on group by has no sense because, only valid value is 2. You need to redefine your query/needs

I guess, your query may be:

```
select ddate,SUM(ntotal) as Income from Inc_orders    
where nbranch=2 
and ddate  between '20100601' and '20100631'   
group by ddate   
order by ddate
```

Comment: I am just giving this as a running example. do not worry about the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the date to a string, just leave it as a date:

```
select ddate,SUM(ntotal) as Income from Inc_orders    
where nbranch=2 
and ddate between '2010-06-01' and '2010-06-31'
group by nbranch   
order by ddate
```

You can convert `ddate` in the select list, if you want it to display in a particular way.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.ok, the thing is i need to use format dd/mm/yyyy on the where clause to,

Comment: Careful with `'yyyy-mm-dd'` - this gets interpreted differently if, say, `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH`. Much safer to use `'yyyymmdd'`.

Comment: how can i make it work with dd-mm-yyyy without changing the languague  ty :)

Answer (score 0):

You may convert document Date by :

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(12),tranInwardHeader.DocumentDate,103),'') AS DocumentDate
```